# How to display records with certain date from an editbox using ms access and delphi 7

Tags: ms-access-2007, delphi-7

I have a table in MS Access with a name MembersAccount and one of the field name as DatePaid. I am trying to display records from a date entered in an editbox but the output is not displaying any records at all. This is the code I am using.

```
if ADOQuery1.Locate('datepaid',edit1.Text,[]) THEN
    begin
    open;
    SQL.Clear;
    qry:= 'Select * from MembersAccount WHERE((MembersAccount.[DatePaid])='+edit1.Text+')';
    SQL.Add(qry);
    Active:= True;
```

Where am I getting the code wrong? Date entered in the editbox is in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: The date delimiter for MS Access is hash # and the format needs to be year, month, day for safety.

Comment: How am I going to use the # delimiter in the above code Fionnuala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parts like these (not full code):

```
editStr := edit.Text;
myDate := StrToDate(editStr);
sqlDate := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', myDate);

qry:= 'Select * from MembersAccount WHERE((MembersAccount.[DatePaid]) = #' + sqlDate + '#)';
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I also added the # delimiter below in my code and it worked well.                                                                                           qry:= 'Select * from MembersAccount WHERE((MembersAccount.[DatePaid])=#'+edit1.Text+'#)';

Comment: Very well, but you also need the correct format for date expression as shown in my answer, or dates with day values of 12 or less will return wrong results.